# Connection java to firebird

Tags: java, hibernate, firebird

I have a Maven project and I generated a `.war` from this project. I have installed a tomcat 32-bit/64-bit Windows Service Installer to deploy.
When I try to make all requisitions who needs access to database, I receive an error 500 Internal Server Error. I think the problem is on persistence.xml, but I don't know what exactly.

- Java 8
- Tomcat 8.5
- Firebird 3.0.3

**persistence.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
     http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0">

 <persistence-unit name="comercialapp" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">

   <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>

   <class>br.com.comercialapp.webservice.model.domain.Cliente</class>

   <properties>

        <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:firebirdsql:localhost/3050:c:\banco\DATABASE.FDB"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="org.firebirdsql.jdbc.FBDriver"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="SYSDBA"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="masterkey"/>


   </properties>
 </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

**pom.xml**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.firebirdsql.jdbc</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaybird-jdk18</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.3</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.6.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

**Error**

```
<!doctype html><html lang="en"><head><title>HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error</title><style type="text/css">h1 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:22px;} h2 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:16px;} h3 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:14px;} body {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:black;background-color:white;} b {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;} p {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;background:white;color:black;font-size:12px;} a {color:black;} a.name {color:black;} .line {height:1px;background-color:#525D76;border:none;}</style></head><body><h1>HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error</h1><hr class="line" /><p><b>Type</b> Exception Report</p><p><b>Message</b> javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named comercialapp</p><p><b>Description</b> The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.</p><p><b>Exception</b></p><pre>javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named comercialapp
org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:432)
org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:370)
org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:389)
org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:342)
org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:229)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

Root Cause

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named comercialapp
    javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:61)
    javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:39)
    br.com.comercialapp.webservice.model.dao.JPAUtil.getEntityManager(JPAUtil.java:14)
    br.com.comercialapp.webservice.model.dao.ClienteDAO.obterTodosPaginacao(ClienteDAO.java:60)
    br.com.comercialapp.webservice.service.ClienteService.obterTodosPaginacao(ClienteService.java:24)
    br.com.comercialapp.webservice.resources.ClienteResource.obterTodosPaginacao(ClienteResource.java:41)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.lambda$static$0(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:76)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:147)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:190)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$TypeOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:243)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:102)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:493)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:415)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:104)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:277)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
    org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:289)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:256)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:703)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:416)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:370)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:389)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:342)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:229)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

**Note** The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the server logs.

#### Apache Tomcat/8.5.31

Comment: Please post the full content of `persistence.xml`, not just a fragment. The error indicates you have configured it wrong.

Comment: Sure, edited now.

Comment: Which Hibernate version are you using and which jars did you add to the classpath?

Comment: <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.6.Final</version>
    </dependency>

Comment: I do not add jar. I generate a .war and deploy it to tomcat server.

Comment: Yes, and the jars of the libraries you depend on should be inside the war. If that is not the case, then that is likely the problem.

Comment: When i enter C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.5\webapps\webservice\WEB-INF\lib  i can see all dependencies from my .war project. Its all here in .jar compressed

Comment: Is that your only hibernate dependency?

Comment: I can't reproduce it. The only thing I can think of is that you are **not** using Hibernate 5.2.x, but an earlier version is pulled in by another dependency, and instead should use `org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence` as the provider, or fix your dependencies.

Comment: I have tested different versions... nothing change. I note the persistence.xml is not in  C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.5\webapps\webservice.

Comment: Yes.. im only using this one hibernate dependency. I tested many different versions in: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-entitymanager

Comment: That sounds like the wrong location, it should end up in `WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/persistence.xml ` (or in `/META-INF/persistence.xml` of one of the jars), which would be an indication that your project has the wrong layout of files. Do you have the message _"HHH000318: Could not find any META-INF/persistence.xml file in the classpath"_ in your logs?

Comment: You are right. You are right. No, there is nothing in my folder deployed. I dont know what is the cause of it. The bug must be on generating .war. Can be eclipse software the cause?

Comment: It's been a while since I used Eclipse, so I would need to look into that to be sure. In a Maven or Gradle project, the `persistence.xml` would need to be in the `src/main/resources/META-INF` folder. For Eclipse it may need to go into something like `src/META-INF` (`src` would then be the folder that also contains your packages).